# Hidden product option

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to use google merchant app for shopify and problem is google requires from you to include product options in certain categories, e.g : color option, which you surely don't want to show as a selective option when your product have one color.

I found that on my css, which doesn't make the job:

```
 // Hide selection box if empty or contain only one selection
 jQuery.each(jQuery('.single-option-selector'), function(index, selection) {
     var option = jQuery(selection).find('option');
     if (option.length <= 1) {
         if (option.first().length && option.first().text().indexOf(defaultTitleText) != -1) {
             jQuery(selection).hide();
```

Any suggestions how should it get fixed?

Comment: "*I found that on my css, which doesn't make the job*" -- I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Can you try to describe the issue in more detail?

Comment: That should be that code that hide a product option if there is only 1 variant available for the option, but it doesn't.

Comment: You will need to provide more detail then. Does `jQuery('.single-option-selector')` return any results? Are you sure that the element you are looking for is part of the same DOM? Is there an iframe?

Comment: I didn't clearly get what jQuery('.single-option-selector') return results means. Yes, elements are from the same DOM, and thats a dropdown menu so i didn't found any iframe involved there. Thanks for help @JDB –

Comment: What happens when you run `jQuery('.single-option-selector')` in the [Chrome Developer Console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/)?

Comment: Nothing! response is '[select#product-select-7756065744product-option-0.single-option-selector, select#product-select-7756065744product-option-1.single-option-selector]' if it helps. PM me if you'd like to fix it for some payment! @JDB